# He said she said

Tags: termination

I was fired over a he said she said situation. I was accused of showing a inappropriate picture on my cell phone to a coworker whom I had never met before going in to fill in at work. We laughed, joked around and then left and went back to the stores in which we both worked. When I went in to my store I got called out by the supervisor and manager and got the sexual harassment talk. I thought that was the end of it.

I worked another week and started management training when the supervisor  told me that I was fired. The supervisor said that HR would cut me my check that afternoon.  I did not sign any termination papers and I didn't receive my check until the next payday.

The coworker that reported me is still working at my format company. I want to know what I can do, because I was out of a job for over a month and got behind on my bills.

Comment: Did you share a NSFW picture? Did you know this person was your coworker before sharing the picture? Do you know if you were fire over the sexual harassment claim or something else?

Answer (score 8):

Now? Nothing. A month has gone by. But a month ago, you should have talked to your supervisor, found out what exactly you were accused of, and denied it. Basically all you can ever do in a situation like this is talk to your boss. Next time, do that.

Answer (score 0):

Studies have shown that sharing NSFW photos with co-workers results in undesirable outcomes.

I recommend that you cease this behavior immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could consult a lawyer to see if there is some compensation you could get but I doubt it.

jcmack pointed out some interesting questions but I think it's probably best to leave it be and just chalk it off as lessons learned.
...unless it keeps haunting you on your next job(s) then you might want to take action against it - though the more time passes the harder that may become.

Behaviour that has been OK just a few years ago is in some countries (mainly USA and Canada and lately some western European countries like the UK) dangerous for your career (if you're lucky) or your financial and private situation (if you're SOL).

Be very mindful about your interactions with your fellow human beings and animals.

Especially if they concern anything that could be interpreted sexual or hateful in nature.